# In BI SSRS I accidentally deleted a group that I need, which contained multiple cells, is there a way to recreate the group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In Microsoft Business Intelligence SSRS I accidentally deleted a ROW Group that I need, but I did not delete the associated cells.  The original group that I deleted contained multiple cells in several rows, even though it was a row group without any children.

I was able to recreate a group with the same name and and settings, but the group consisted of only a single row, and by default it added a new row.  I was able to delete the new row without deleting the group, but still, the group is a single row, when I need cells in multiple rows, like was in the report before.

Can I add cells and/or rows to this group so that I can get it back to how it was?

Edit:

The first image is of the current row group that is only one row (highlighted) but I want to change to be like the group in the second image (also highlighted), which is how the group was, originally before I deleted it.  The second image is also a ROW group, and was started with the default Details Group.

[image: This is an image of the current group highlighted. It is a row group and it is only one row.]

[image: The second image is of the how the ROW group was, And that group was actually started from the default Details Group.]

Comment: Did you try Undo (Ctrl + Z) command? If you did not close VS it should take back the report to previous states.

Comment: Ctrl+Z boat has sailed.  Not an option at this point.

Comment: If you can't provide a before and (at least) after screenshot of what you have done, you are going to struggle to get any good responses here.

Comment: Did you deploy your original report? You could download the old one from the **Report Server** and put in your BI folder, overwriting the version that has the missing group.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Basically the only way to recreate the group is to create a new group, add a bunch of rows, and copy & paste the information from the rows that were in the removed group to the new rows.  Reformat as needed.  It took only a couple minutes.